# Rendering data from HTTP POST Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, http

I'm kinda new to Angular and I need to do a function that does an http.post on click and it works (POST DONE is returned and I get the data), the problem is that i need to render data inside tables but 'postReponse' returns only [Object Object] in my html file and I can't find a way to render the data as it should, does anyone have a fix for this issue please ?

Here's the code sample :

```
public postReponse: any;

postRefs(){
    return this.httpClient.post('someUrl',
      {
        "someBody"

      })
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("POST DONE", data)
          return this.postResponse = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log("ERROR POST", error)
        }
      )
  }

//home.component.html

            <tr>
              <td>{{postResponse}}</td>
              <td>{{postResponse}}</td>
              <td>{{postResponse}}</td>
              <td>{{postResponse}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

postResponse is an object with keys and values, for example if it contains two attributes id and name then it will look like this :

```
{ id : 1, name = 'name' }
```

So if you need to access to the name attribute you need to write inside your html:

```
<td>{{postResponse.name}}</td>
```

Comment: When I do the following I'm getting this error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined and it still render as [Object Object] after click the button to do the post that's why I don't get it

Comment: before you use the postResponse variable check if it's available : <tbody *ngIf="postResponse">

Comment: Thank's, this one correct the error but it still renders as [Object Object], do I need to convert the output I get from the JSON ?

Comment: log the response data to the console and share it

Comment: POST DONE 
{crossPart: {…}, ecom: Array(0)}
crossPart:
all: (2) [{…}, {…}]
found: [{…}]
noequivalent: [{…}]
unrecognized: (2) [{…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
ecom: []
__proto__: Object

Comment: use this.postResponse = data.json()

Comment: json() does not work in my Project, HttpClient deserializes the content of a response into an object so I can't use it

Comment: try to test your api with postman for example and check the response format

Comment: Here's Postman result `{"crossPart":{"found":[],"noequivalent":[],"unrecognized":[{"articleSociete":"15008617","raisonSociale":"","articleSI":"","libelle":""}],"all":[]},"ecom":[]}`, data is rendered as an Object but I can't find a way to render it as string, already tried with JSON.stringify